# What piece is designed to hold the "drawer" piece?

Tags: piece-usage

Cruising the good old PAB, I come across a piece called simply, the "drawer". From the image, I can conclude that this piece is meant to act like a real drawer, by pulling out of something.

Question: What is that something? What is designed to hold the drawer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part you are looking for is [4532a - Container, Cupboard 2 x 3 x 2 - Solid Studs](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4532a#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D). There is also a 4532 version with hollow studs.

[image]